# How can I create a spinner within a fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, spinner

I'm trying to create a spinner in a fragment but while making the spinner dialog it fails to recognize the fragment java class using ".this". I'm not sure what I should be doing instead and any help would be greatly appreciated. (Dialog is defined in OnCreate method)

```
ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
SpinnerDialog spinnerDialog;
Button add;

spinnerDialog = new SpinnerDialog(Add.this, ingredients, "Select An Ingredient");
    spinnerDialog.bindOnSpinerListener(new OnSpinerItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String Ingredient, int i) {

            Toast.makeText(Add.super.getContext(), "Selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    add = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Add.this` with `getActivity()`.

It's hard to say for sure exactly what the problem is (since I don't know how `SpinnerDialog` is implemented), but chances are very good that the constructor's first argument is a `Context`. `Fragment`s do not implement `Context`, but `Activity`s do. So instead of passing in your `Fragment` instance, pass in its containing `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

`Add.this` is context parameter.

If `Add.class` is a fragment, use `getActivity()` when passing the context parameter.

But if `Add.class` is an activity, is `Add.this` instead.